# Creating an overlay view ontop of EAGLView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, opengl-es

I am creating a game using OpenGLES.
Game consists of a view controller and the EAGLView.
I have created another view controller that I want to handle the extra view that go ontop of the EAGLView so things like menu and options.
I have a call from the EAGLView view controller to the extra view controller that adds an IBOUTLET UIView to the appdelegates window however its not appearing. The methods being called but no view is being added.
Probably a really easy and stupid question but I cant work it out.
Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: If by EAGLView you mean a UIView subclass with a CAEAGLLayer backing it, you deal with this view like you would any other UIView.  There's nothing special about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have done it a different way.
I use a view Controller called GameViewController to load up and i add its subview to the window in the appDelegates applicationDidFinishLaunching method
Then i call a method to add another view controllers view (my open gl view) to the subview.   This means I can then put other views over the top.
I don't know why i didn't do this before to be honest
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific with this sentence:

> I have a call from the EAGLView view controller to the extra view controller that adds an IBOUTLET UIView to the appdelegates window however its not appearing.

One approach is to use navigation controller that could be initalized with EAGLView controller as root. So, you can push and pop in navigation controller another view controller that handles the game menus.

Another approach is to present menu as modal view controller. This can be invoked with presentModalViewController: in current EAGLView controller.